# Unable to Install Packages on RCloud

Tags: rcloud

I am unable to install packages and have tried installing packages through devtools with no success. Seems I can not create a library to hold installed packages. Our we allowed to install packages on RCloud? or is there no space for us to install packages to begin with? I get the following errors: 
    
    `#1ERROR: failed to create lock directory /shared/users/rcloud/danielra0091/library/00LOCK-digest’`

    
    `#2ERROR: unable to create ‘/shared/users/rcloud/danielra0091/library/rbenchmark’`

````
```
library(devtools)
install_github("HenrikBengtsson/future") 

Results: 
Downloading GitHub repo HenrikBengtsson/future@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/HenrikBengtsson/future/zipball/master
Installing future
trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/digest_0.6.18.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 128553 bytes (125 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 125 KB

Installing digest
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmprSADLu-danielra0091/devtools22293a652eab/digest'  \
  --library='/shared/users/rcloud/danielra0091/library' --install-tests 

Error: Command failed (3)
trace:
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
vapply(remotes, install_remote, ..., FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
install_remotes(remotes, quiet = quiet, ...)
install_github("HenrikBengtsson/future")


-------------------------------------------------------------------------


install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock')) 


Results:
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmprSADLu-danielra0091/downloaded_packages’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c("--no-lock")) :
  installation of package ‘inline’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c("--no-lock")) :
  installation of package ‘rbenchmark’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c("--no-lock")) :
  installation of package ‘pinp’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c("--no-lock")) :
  installation of package ‘pkgKitten’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c("--no-lock")) :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```
````

Comment: I believe this question is specific to our internal deployment of RCloud (on KM). Have you asked / searched on internal Stack? I think the issue is devtools vs standard `install.packages` - I think it's possible to get devtools to work but it's more difficult. Can't recall the difficulties atm but I'm hoping someone covered it on tStack.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if you install packages yourself, they will be installed in your personal library.  You may also request package installation from your server admins which will be installed for everyone in the RCloud instance.

One issue you may be running into with your local (or personal library) installation is that you need to set up a proxy to get outside your firewall to the installation libraries / packages in public domains.

Another may be due to the R and RCloud version that is currently installed.  If you think that might be the case, I would contact your RCloud admins.